# How to Get Package Name of Source Class File in Android ?

Tags: java, android, class, android-library, package-managers

I am using only one project to port lite and full versions for that I am just updating Manifest file package names.

My project structure is like this

My App 
       |_src 
            |_com.example.myapp 
                                                 |_MyClass.java

and my Manifest package name is different.

package="com.example.myapplite"

I am using one library project in that I want package names of classes that I am using in MyApp.

I have used this

```
        System.out.println("Package Name " + context.getPackageName());
```

But its giving me a Manifest file package name value ie. *com.example.myapplite*

I want MyClass.java package name. ie. *com.example.myapp*

Also I am aware about this

```
 MyClass mClass = new MyClass();
 Package pack = mClass.getClass().getPackage();
```

But I can't use this approach because I am using following approach to get class file in my library project

```
Class c = Class.forName("package_name.MyClass");
```

How to get package name of MyClass.java file programmatically?

Comment: Try use this: YourClass.class.getPackage().getName();

Comment: It's not clear why you'd use `new MyClass().getClass()` (effectively) rather than just `MyClass.class`... or why that's not enough for you. Your explanation of using `Class.forName` doesn't really explain what you're trying to do. What do you *wish* you could do that `Class.getPackage()` doesn't do for you?

Comment: I am using library project, to use MyClass in my library project I need to access it Class.forName("package_name.MyClass"); because library project dosent aware about MyClass.java

Comment: Also I cant create object of MyClass before accessing it.

Answer (score 12):

Might Be helpfull

```
package org.kodejava.example.lang;
import java.util.Date;

public class ObtainingPackageName {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //
    // Create an instance of Date class, and then obtain the class package
    // name.
    //
    Date date = new Date();
    Package pack = date.getClass().getPackage();
    String packageName = pack.getName();
    System.out.println("Package Name = " + packageName);

    //
    // Create an insatnce of our class and again get its package name
    //
    ObtainingPackageName o = new ObtainingPackageName();
    packageName = o.getClass().getPackage().getName();
    System.out.println("Package Name = " + packageName);
   }
}
```

Comment: I using library project so I cant create object of MyClass before accessing it. I am using  Class.forName("package_name.MyClass"); to access that class for that I need package name.

Comment: Be aware that Class.getPackage() can return null if the class loader for the class does not register the package. This is typically done from within the ClassLoader by using ClassLoader.definePackage(). You can see this in action in for example URLClassLoader. If you're not installing a custom ClassLoader, you shouldn't have any problem as the default ClassLoader will define packages while loading classes.

Comment: What's the output?

Answer (score 5):

The Kotlin solution:

```
val packageName = this.javaClass.`package`?.name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String packageName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
```

will work definitely.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
    try {
        Class c = Class.forName("package_name.MyClass");

        Object o = c.newInstance();

        Package p = o.getClass().getPackage();

        System.out.println("Package Name :: " + p.getName());

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This solution seems to be good, but is there a way to get the package name for this without creating a new instance?

Comment: @FelipeMosso just use `.getClass().getPackage().getName()` on any instance or use `[YourClassName].class.getPackage().getName()`

Answer (score 1):

Simple example of some class `NotificationListener`:

```
Timber.d(NotificationListener.class.getPackage().getName());
Timber.d(NotificationListener.class.getSimpleName());
Timber.d(NotificationListener.class.getName());
```

Output:

```
D/PermissionsUtil: com.example.receivers
D/PermissionsUtil: NotificationListener
D/PermissionsUtil: com.example.receivers.NotificationListener
```