# What is initClickListener(), ComponentName, class.getPackage()?

Tags: java, android

I am an android newbie also not very affluent with java. I am trying to to understand MobiStego source code.

Hence the following is a part of the project code I fail to understand fully.

Please help....

```
private void initClickListner()
    {
        Button buttonEncode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonEncode);
        buttonEncode.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 Intent intent = new Intent();

                  intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(EncodeActivity.class.getPackage().getName(),
                          EncodeActivity.class.getCanonicalName()));
                  startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-initClickListner() is a method that who is made herself. User method. Like;

public void myfunction(){
.....
.....
}

2-setcomponent and class.getpackage are kind of intent component. I suppose u know intent mechanism in android. This intent type for different package names in application. For example u have com.axample.yourappname and com.example.yourappname2 packages. This intent, cross intent for different package activities. If u want to call activity of second package from activity of first package u can call above function.

Comment: thanks a lot, but please tell me how to figure out the number of packages in my android project and btw what does the term getCanonicalName mean....?

Comment: Default u have 1 package in your app. Under your project u must see brown bundle. This is your package. If u right click on your project in eclipse and add new package u can see your second package.
getCanonicalName;
ClassDemo c = new ClassDemo();
     Class cls = c.getClass();

     // returns the canonical name of the underlying class if it exists
     System.out.println("Class = " + cls.getCanonicalName());

Comment: Mark this question for apply dude.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend MehmetF's answer only. As he said, `initClickListner()` is only a user-defined method name, nothing special than that.
`ComponentName` acts as an `identifier` for a specific application component, this component may be an `activity` or a `service`.
`class.getPackage().getName()` is used to get the package name of the specified Class name before it.
These 2 links will also help you to have a clear idea:

- [ComponentName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html)
- [How to Get Package Name of Source Class File in Android ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889694/how-to-get-package-name-of-source-class-file-in-android)

EDIT:
`class.getCanonicalName()` is the name that is used in an import statement and **uniquely identifies the class**. Well, i think you need to see these differences to understand clearly.

- [What is the difference between canonical name, simple name and class name in Java Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202997/what-is-the-difference-between-canonical-name-simple-name-and-class-name-in-jav)

Comment: If you think that solves your problem then mark it as answer so that it can help others also.